# Report Services login

Tags: reporting-services, windows-server-2012

I have a problem in which I cannot log into http://****/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx or  http://****/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx from an application.  I can put the URL in a browser and log in and then run the application and it will do what it is supposed to do but cannot log in using the following:

```
public class MyReportRenderer
{
    private rs2005.ReportingService2005 rs;
    private rs2005Execution.ReportExecutionService rsExec;

    public void RenderTest(String matchedCaseNumber)
    {
        string HistoryID = (string)null;
        string DeviceInfo = (string)null;
        string MimeType = string.Empty;
        string Encoding = string.Empty;
        string Extension = string.Empty;
        ReportGenerator.rs2005Execution.Warning[] Warnings = (ReportGenerator.rs2005Execution.Warning[])null;
        string[] StreamIds = (string[])null;
        this.rs = new ReportingService2005();
        this.rsExec = new ReportExecutionService();
        //this.rs.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        //this.rsExec.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        this.rs.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("****", "****", "WIN-2MUFL6FJSPL");
        this.rsExec.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("****", "****", "WIN-2MUFL6FJSPL");
        this.rs.Url = "****/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx";
        this.rsExec.Url = "****/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx";

        try
        {
            // Load the selected report.
            this.rsExec.LoadReport("/LawDept/LawDeptTIC", HistoryID);

            // Set the parameters for the report needed.

            rs2005Execution.ParameterValue[] parameters = new rs2005Execution.ParameterValue[1];
            parameters[0] = new rs2005Execution.ParameterValue();
            parameters[0].Name = "CaseNumberKey";
            parameters[0].Value = matchedCaseNumber;

            rsExec.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "en-us");

            // get pdf of report 
            byte[] buffer = this.rsExec.Render("PDF", DeviceInfo, out Extension, out MimeType, out Encoding, out Warnings, out StreamIds);
            DataClasses1DataContext classes1DataContext = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            Queryable.SingleOrDefault<string>(Queryable.Select<vw_ProductClientInfo, string>(Queryable.Where<vw_ProductClientInfo>((IQueryable<vw_ProductClientInfo>)classes1DataContext.GetTable<vw_ProductClientInfo>(), (Expression<Func<vw_ProductClientInfo, bool>>)(c => c.CaseNumberKey == matchedCaseNumber)), (Expression<Func<vw_ProductClientInfo, string>>)(c => c.Description)));
            string str1 = Queryable.SingleOrDefault<string>(Queryable.Select<vw_ProductClientInfo, string>(Queryable.Where<vw_ProductClientInfo>((IQueryable<vw_ProductClientInfo>)classes1DataContext.GetTable<vw_ProductClientInfo>(), (Expression<Func<vw_ProductClientInfo, bool>>)(c => c.CaseNumberKey == matchedCaseNumber)), (Expression<Func<vw_ProductClientInfo, string>>)(c => c.Summary)));
            string str2 = Queryable.SingleOrDefault<string>(Queryable.Select<vw_ProductClientInfo, string>(Queryable.Where<vw_ProductClientInfo>((IQueryable<vw_ProductClientInfo>)classes1DataContext.GetTable<vw_ProductClientInfo>(), (Expression<Func<vw_ProductClientInfo, bool>>)(c => c.CaseNumberKey == matchedCaseNumber)), (Expression<Func<vw_ProductClientInfo, string>>)(c => string.Format("{0:C}", (object)c.Total))));
            string str3 = Queryable.SingleOrDefault<string>(Queryable.Select<vw_ProductClientInfo, string>(Queryable.Where<vw_ProductClientInfo>((IQueryable<vw_ProductClientInfo>)classes1DataContext.GetTable<vw_ProductClientInfo>(), (Expression<Func<vw_ProductClientInfo, bool>>)(c => c.CaseNumberKey == matchedCaseNumber)), (Expression<Func<vw_ProductClientInfo, string>>)(c => c.BRTNumber)));
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage("Reports@aalacquest.com", Queryable.SingleOrDefault<string>(Queryable.Select<vw_ProductClientInfo, string>(Queryable.Where<vw_ProductClientInfo>((IQueryable<vw_ProductClientInfo>)classes1DataContext.GetTable<vw_ProductClientInfo>(), (Expression<Func<vw_ProductClientInfo, bool>>)(c => c.CaseNumberKey == matchedCaseNumber)), (Expression<Func<vw_ProductClientInfo, string>>)(c => c.Email))), "Report for Property " + Queryable.SingleOrDefault<string>(Queryable.Select<vw_ProductClientInfo, string>(Queryable.Where<vw_ProductClientInfo>((IQueryable<vw_ProductClientInfo>)classes1DataContext.GetTable<vw_ProductClientInfo>(), (Expression<Func<vw_ProductClientInfo, bool>>)(c => c.CaseNumberKey == matchedCaseNumber)), (Expression<Func<vw_ProductClientInfo, string>>)(c => c.Premises))), "Tax Information Certificate.");
            MailAddress mailAddress = new MailAddress("george.greiner@aalacquest.com");
            ((Collection<MailAddress>)message.CC).Add(mailAddress);
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("localhost");
            message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment((Stream)new MemoryStream(buffer), string.Format("{0}" + str3 + ".pdf", (object)"BRT")));
            smtpClient.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Any help figuring out why I cannot log in would be greatly appreciated.  The credentials are of course valid.

Comment: Unless something else not apparent in your function is relying on ReportingService2005 then you should be able to do everything in the procedure above using only rsExec=new ReportExecution2005.ReportExecutionService(). No need for the rs credentials for render.

Comment: What is returned when you run this in your application without doing the login via url as you described?